# Transitional Expand/Collapse animations(Specific) in Expandable RecyclerView with Multiple Children

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I have been looking around for a while and can't seem to find an Expandable RecyclerView with multiple children that would support transitional animations like the one in https://michiganlabs.com/android/development/2017/01/18/expand-collapse-recycler-view/.

The reason this is still an issue is because there are multiple binds in the Adapter. I'd still like to know if it was possible though.

I am currently using the Expandable RecyclerView by bignerdranch. If there is a better library to use for this, please send it my way.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a library that is very useful for this.

https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators will help with animating any recyclerview. Check out his GitHub for more information.